# Mistake when learning list

Tags: python

I wrote this code to check my understanding on list function in Python:

```
ten = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = input('Position of the value you want to add ')
b = int(b)
a = input('Enter the value you want to add to list')
a = int(a)
ten.insert(b,a)

print(ten)

print('The lenght of this list is '+str(len(ten)))
sotim = input('Number you want to check')
sotim = int(sotim)
if sotim in ten:
    print('The number you ask is at position '+str(ten.index(sotim))+' in the list')
else:
    print('The number you ask is not in the list')
```

For example when b = 999
and a = 18

The ten.index(sotim) should be 10 instead of 9 when I run the program.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that sotim = 18

Comment: There are 9 elements in your list. When you call insert(i,x) where i >= len(ten) the value x will be appended to the list. It does **not** fill the list with values up to position i

Comment: Python's index is 0-based, so 9 means the 10th element.

Comment: Thank you @InSync I just noticed it. So I should understand 9 as 10th element and it gives a correct answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you input b=999, a=18 and sotim also = 18.

So what that does is, it tries to insert the number 18 at position 999, but since the length of the list is shorter(length 9), it just appends it at the end.

The reason why it returns 9 is because it is the 10'th element of the list (counting in "natural numbers"), but the corresponding index is "9" (since the python numbering of lists, arrays etc. starts with "0".